# How to store text embedding of varying size for RNN in python?

Tags: dataset, recurrent-neural-network, word-embedding

I'm training an classifier for text using Word2vec and RNN (pytorch).

I would like to embed all of my instances of text with varying lengths via word2vec, and store them in a csv file.

I'm considering storing them as strings, but I'm not convicted this is a good solution.

**What's a convenient way to store the embeddings?**

Answer (score 1):

If you generate a csv file, you can store it in pickle format. Pandas provides an easy way to read pickle files
If you have a dataframe of the form ['text', 'word2vec_embedding'] then you can store it to pickle as

```
df.to_pickle(filepath)
```

and loaded as a dataframe by

```
df = pd.read_pickle(filepath)
```

[Documentation for pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html)